# Systems of inequations and counting constraint

Tags: constraint-satisfaction

I am playing with Gecode to solve a problem where you label the arcs of a multi-digraph such that the sums of the arc labels in each path from a single source to a single sink come from a multiset. So for example we might have a graph with 8 paths and want path arc sums to come from the set {5,5,5,4,3,2,1,0}. So we must have exactly 3 paths with a sum of 5 and 5 paths with a unique sum of 0..4.

You can reformulate this problem as asking if some permutation of {5,5,5,4,3,2,1,0} is in the column space of the path arc incidence matrix of the graph.
I model this multiset match with the "count" constraint. The arc sums are linear equations.

My graphs have many parallel edges that come in pairs. Using symmetry I use this to impose a partial order on the path sums. This also means that there are sets of pairs of path sums that have the same difference. So from my example if the paths are b0...b7 I have the following pair sets:

b0 - b1 = b3 - b4 = b5 - b6, b0 - b2 = b5 - b7, b0 - b3 = b1 - b4, b0 - b5 = b1 - b6 = b2 - b7

b1 - b2 = b6 - b7, b3 - b5 = b4 - b6

Including these differences into the model seems to cut down the search space by two orders of magnitude in Gecode. I am pleased with this because I think it's telling me something important about the graphs I am studying and it fits with some conjectures in the area I work in.

The partial order now tells us that only b0,b2,b3,b5 and b7 may take the value 5.
It's possible to now prove this system can not be satisfied. I am interested in techniques from constraint satisfaction etc that can be used to analyse a system of inequations (!=) along with "count". Obviously Gecode can prove this by assigning values and failing. I am interested in general techniques to both learn about constraint satisfaction, help improve the model and maybe gain some understanding of the things I am investigating.

To see the problem is not soluble we can show that each of the 6 sets of pair difference systems can not have a difference of zero. If they did they would generate duplicates of the wrong values or too many 5's.

For example b0 - b1 = b3 - b4 = b5 - b6 would have b0 = b1 which is impossible since b1 can not be 5 and that's the only value that can have duplicates.
Or b0 - b2 = b5 - b7 would mean that b0 = b2 and b5 = b7 requiring 4 5's.

So we end up with a set of inequations on the paths whose sum could be 5:

b0 != b2, b0 != b3, b0 != b5, b2 != b7, b5 != b7

We can see that b0 != 5 since if it was we could only get 2 fives. From the remaining 4 values we are forced to be able to set at most two to 5 so the whole system is insoluble.